# Link desde un list-group dentro de una tab hacia siguiente tab

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un bootstrap wizard con progress bar, el ejemplo original es que cada vez que se hace click en una tab avance la barra de progreso, mi intención es aprovechar este código para insertar en cada tab un list-group y que al hacer click en cualquiera de los elementos del list-group me lleve a la siguiente tab.
Me pueden echar una manito con esto por favor.

De antemano muchas gracias por cualquier muestra de colaboración.

Saludos.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bar" class="progress" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria- 
    valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Wizard" class="wizard">
    <ul style="">
        <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Datos Personales</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Solicitud Matricula</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Ebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Resumen</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
        <h2>¿Cuántas personas trabajan en tu empresa?</h2>  
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">a. Sólo yo</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">b. Entre 2 y 10 personas</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">c. Más de 10 personas</a>                   
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <h2>¿Qué sistema operativo utilizas en tu computador?</h2>
        <div class="list-group wizard">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">a. No uso computador</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">b. No sé / No estoy 
            seguro</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">c. Windows</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">d. MacOS</a>
            <a href="#tab3" class="list-group-item">e. Linux</a>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        Ebook
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
        Resumen
    </div>

    <ul class="pager wizard">
        <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Primero</a></li>
        <li class="previous"><a href="#">Anterior</a></li>
        <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Ultimo</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a href="#">Siguiente</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#').bootstrapWizard();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
        var $current = index+1;
        var $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
        $('.progress-bar').css({width:$percent+'%'});
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para efectuar lo que indicas, podrías pulsar sobre el botón next cuando se haya seleccionado una opción. Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#').bootstrapWizard();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
        var $current = index+1;
        var $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
        $('.progress-bar').css({width:$percent+'%'});
    }});
});

$(document).ready(function()  {
  $('.list-group-item').click(function () {
    var tabs = $('.tab-content').children();
    var tabsLength = tabs.length;
    var i = 0;
    // recorremos los tabs para obtener el indice del tab activo (actual)
    for (i = 0; i < tabsLength; i++) {
      if ($(tabs[i]).attr("class").includes('active')) break;
    }
    // si el tab activo actual es diferente al último pulsamos sobre el boton next
    if (i < (tabsLength - 1)) {
      $('.next').filter(function() { return !$(this).attr('class').includes('last') }).click();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
<div id="bar" class="progress" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria- 
    valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Wizard" class="wizard">
    <ul style="">
        <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Datos Personales</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Solicitud Matricula</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Ebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Resumen</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
        <h2>¿Cuántas personas trabajan en tu empresa?</h2>  
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">a. Sólo yo</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">b. Entre 2 y 10 personas</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">c. Más de 10 personas</a>                   
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <h2>¿Qué sistema operativo utilizas en tu computador?</h2>
        <div class="list-group wizard">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">a. No uso computador</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">b. No sé / No estoy 
            seguro</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">c. Windows</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">d. MacOS</a>
            <a href="#tab3" class="list-group-item">e. Linux</a>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <h2>¿Qué sistema operativo utilizas en tu computador?</h2>
        <div class="list-group wizard">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">a. No uso computador</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">b. No sé / No estoy 
            seguro</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">c. Windows</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">d. MacOS</a>
            <a href="#tab3" class="list-group-item">e. Linux</a>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
        <h2>¿Qué sistema operativo utilizas en tu computador?</h2>
        <div class="list-group wizard">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">a. No uso computador</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">b. No sé / No estoy 
            seguro</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">c. Windows</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">d. MacOS</a>
            <a href="#tab3" class="list-group-item">e. Linux</a>
        </div> 
      </div>

    <ul class="pager wizard">
        <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Primero</a></li>
        <li class="previous"><a href="#">Anterior</a></li>
        <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Ultimo</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a href="#">Siguiente</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Excelente Osiris, eso necesitaba.
Te lo agradezco mucho. Éxito!!!